# LibreOffice Calc で印刷範囲が左右中央にならない

Tags: 印刷, libreoffice

ネットで調べた方法（書式＞ページ＞拡大縮小モード:印刷範囲をページ数に合わせる）
を行っても、印刷範囲が真ん中にならず、右側に大きく余白が出来てしまいました。
（1ページには収まりました）
縦横に中央配置で印刷する方法が分かる方は教えていただけますでしょうか。

よろしくお願いします。

Comment: 書式＞ページ＞のページタブの余白の値はどうなっていますか？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

書式＞ページ＞の「ページ」タブのレイアウト設定に「表の配置」の設定項目があります。
この設定項目の「横中央」と「縦中央」のチェックボックスにチェックを入れると、印刷範囲の中央に表が表示されます。
【チェックなし】
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

【チェックあり】
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

この例は右余白を「5.00cm」としています。

Comment: 「横中央」と「縦中央」にチェックを入れると中央配置で印刷することが出来ました。
ご回答いただきましてありがとうございます。
大変助かりました！！